# ReactJS - Input Components data passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm writing my first components and I have a problem with data binding

What I would like to have is to get values of fields in my LoginView so I may pass them further in handleSubmit into a function which does a request to the backend.

I had written previously this form without component but then I've decided to improve it by splitting each piece of form into small components.

The problem is that I don't understand how data passing between LoginView and TextInput works.

**TextInput Component**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

class TextInput extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    type: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.any
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {is_valid: true}
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event, this.props)
    this.props.value = event.target.value
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  render() {
    var divClasses = classNames({
      'form-group': true,
      'has-danger': !this.state.is_valid
    })
    var inputClasses = classNames({
      'form-control': true,
      'form-control-danger': !this.state.is_valid
    })
    console.log(this.props.value)
    return (
      <div className={divClasses}>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.label}</label>
        <input type={this.props.type} className={inputClasses}
               id={'id_'+ this.props.name}
               placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
               name={this.props.name}
               value={this.props.value}
               onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TextInput
```

**View**

```
import React from 'react'
import TextInput from 'components/TextInput'
import EmailInput from 'components/EmailInput'
import PasswordInput from 'components/PasswordInput'

export class LoginView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      remember_me: false
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value)
    var key = e.target.name
    var value = e.target.value.trim()
    var data = {}
    data[key] = value
    this.setState(data)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-offset-4 col-md-4'>
          <form role='form' className='form form-horizontal' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate="novalidate">
            <TextInput name='Email' label='Email' type='text' placeholder='Email' value={this.state.email} />
            <PasswordInput value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
            <div className='checkbox'>
              <label><input type='checkbox' name='remmeber_me' onChange={this.handleChange}/> Keep me logged in</label>
            </div>
            <div className='clearfix'>
              <button className='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' type='submit'>Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginView
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between two components is much easier when they have a parent to child relationship. For parent-child communication, simply pass props. 
link to React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

"In React, an owner is the component that sets the props of other components. More formally, if a component X is created in component Y's render() method, it is said that X is owned by Y. As discussed earlier, a component cannot mutate its props — they are always consistent with what its owner sets them to. This fundamental invariant leads to UIs that are guaranteed to be consistent."

Generally it is better to have one 'parent' component that handles all the state changes

More on ownership here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#ownership